# Search API data in Ionic 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic4

I want to search data from the API(backend -> php).
I get the data correctly, but I have a problem with *ngFor and the searchbar.
It only shows the search button when the input in the searchbar field is correct. So when I go to the website, the search button is not shown, it only appears when the input in the searcbar is stored in the database. 
How to make the search button always shown, even when the input is not existing in the database.

home.page.html

```
<ion-grid >
        <ion-row >

            <ion-col size-xs="12" size-sm="12" size-md="8" size-lg="8">
                <ion-searchbar placeholder="Restaurant" [(ngModel)]="searchTermName" (ionChange)="searchName($event)"></ion-searchbar>
            </ion-col>

        </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>

    <div class="btn" *ngFor="let item of (results | async)">
            <ion-button [routerLink]="['/', 'details', item.reid]" color="primary" fill="solid">
                search
            </ion-button>
        </div>

    </div>
```

home.page.ts

```
searchName() {
    this.results = this.userService.getName(this.searchTermName);
    console.log(this.results);
  }
```

user.service.ts

```
 getName(name1) {
    return this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/searchRestaurantByName', {headers: {name: name1}}).pipe(
        map(name => {
            console.log('RAW: ', name1);
            return name;
        })
    );
  }
```

'asd' is in the database a restaurant
[image: asd is in the database a restaurant]

when i type nothing, there is no button??
[image]

Comment: You only show your button when you have a result...

Answer (score 0):

Home.ts

```
searchName() {
   this.userService.getName(this.searchTermName).subscribe((responce) => {
    console.log(responce);
})
```

Change your way of code, keep subscribe promise, untill get responce from API.

Answer (score 0):

You only show your button when you have a result. So we could change you code like the example below. When the value is changed in the searchbar, your names are requested in the userService. When the value returns in `results`, an item is shown below the searchbar.

You don't really need a button to search, because the function is executed when the value of the searchbar changes. If you want a button, then you can delete the ionChange event and get the value when you click your search button.

This is just an example to represent how you could do this. You can modify this for your own needs or think of another way to achieve your goals.

```html
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col size-xs="12" size-sm="12" size-md="8" size-lg="8">
      <ion-searchbar placeholder="Restaurant" (ionChange)="searchName($event.target.value)"></ion-searchbar>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-item routerLink="['/', 'details', item.reid]" *ngFor="let item of (results | async)">
        {{ item.name }}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

```js
searchName(searchValue: string) {
  this.userService.getName(searchValue).subscribe((result: object) => {
    this.users = result;
  });
}
```

Comment: I need the button because when the user search for a restaurant in the input field and then clicks on the button, the profile for the restaurant should display on anohter page.

Comment: how do I get the value when i click on the button?

Comment: Use `[(ngModel)]="searchTermName"` on your searchbar to get the value of the search. Make a button and set the CLICK event to `searchName()` function. There you can access the searchvalue from  `searchTermName`